# XML source formatter not working on plugin.xml sources

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatting, rcp

I have a normal eclipse plugin project with a plugin.xml file.
Since i am using a sonar sever with XML checks I want the file to be indented in a specific way.

The eclipse XML auto formatter however is not available when i view the XML with the plugin-manifest-editor (clicking the plugin.xml source tab on the bottom of the editor)

I already tried to configure the Hotkeys in eclipse to run the formatter in this specific context but I can't seem to find the correct context.

Is auto formatting in this editor just not possible or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think the plugin.xml editor has any support for formatting.